# How do I make the splash screen as quick as possible?

Tags: splash-screen, maui

I'd like to defer as much loading as possible away from the splash screen and into a view page with a loading animation. How can I achieve that since I can't have the splash screen itself show a loading animation?

Comment: The "quickest" solution would be native on each platform, and defer Maui app startup until your native loading screen is showing an animation. Looking at default Maui project, Android folder, the "magic" must happen in `MauiAppCompatActivity`, which `MainActivity` inherits from. You could look at Maui source code on Android, and start with an Activity that inherits directly from the standard Android Activity. Then once that is running animation, start the Maui app load process.

Answer (score 1):

`MauiSplashScreen` should have supported `Animation`, however, this has hasn't been implemented and is a feature request: [[Enhancement] MauiSplashScreen Video / Animation Support](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/3300). The best we can do on `Android 12` is trying to **ignore** or **dismiss** the `SplashScreen` through the `OnCreate` method below which would save the loading time.

```
public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity 
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

    }
}
```

For more details, you can refer to [Customize the animation for dismissing the splash screen](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen#customize-animation)